On-bike pump maintenance requirements?
I have a variety of small bike pumps, both mini-pumps like a Topeak Race Rocket and small floor-pumps like the Topeak Road Morph.  They live on their bike all the time, and suffer the same vibrations and moisture and dirt as the rest of the bike.
What maintenance should be done to ensure the pump will work when required, and how often?
Related - do Gauges and CO2 fittings and hoses need special consideration ?


I would highly recommend checking the pump occasionally if it's unused for long periods. Nothing is worse than a pump you used 2 years ago last, that doesn't work anymore to pump a tire after a flat.

I'm on my second  Road Morph Road Morph(or third, I can't remember whether the stolen one was a Road or Mini Morph), and I had a couple of issues with the first (second?).
The gauge partially  stuck, causing me to blow out a tyre (a studded winter tyre rated max 85 psi, with the suggestion to run close to the max if there's no snow). I pumped it until I was sore and blew the sidewall out a few minutes later.  Later testing suggested I'd got well over 100psi and the tyre was far from new.  When I opened up the gauge it was full of rusty water and the spring was rough with rust.  That had been left on my bike all winter and our winters are wet.
While on a long tour, I found however hard I worked I couldn't get my tyres as firm as I'd like, barely enough to ride on.  At a campsite, I stripped it down and regreased the O-ring in the main barrel, which sorted the problem .  A couple of years later I replaced the O-ring*, and a couple of years after that went to regrease it but stripped the (rather fragile) screw thread that  retains the output tube.  It no longer sealed there, but I salvaged parts from a Mini Morph to repair it.  Be gentle in that area of the pump.
The reason I replaced it in the end is that I destroyed the top cap trying to strip it again for cleaning/greasing.  You can use the T handle to unscrew the cap that it bayonets into for storage, and withdraw the piston, but only if it's not jammed.  This was jammed and my other tools trashed the plastic.
So in summary, every year or two depending on conditions, strip and regrease the main O ring.  Test the pump and gauge occasionally by pumping a tyre to full pressure with it, using either another gauge to check, or a thumb and common sense.

* I couldn't find a replacement O ring for that pump, but managed to find one in a set meant for plumbing

Don't forget the seal that seals the pump against the tire valve. If this gets old the rubber gets hard and does no longer seal that well.

I’ve used Lezyne Pressure Drive and Sport Drive pumps for ~10 years in all weather and over tens of thousands of kilometers. They are mounted to the bottle cage so see a lot of dirt and water. I pretty much only use them when I have a puncture while on the road.
My only issue so far has been that the threads of the (removable) hose where it screws onto the valve failed after not too many uses (maybe 20). Fortunately it still barely engaged for the last time I needed it and I ordered a replacement hose. Kind of surprising and disappointing.
Every few years I open the pumps, clean them and lubricate with silicone lubricant. They all still work smoothly.

For the most part, I think the pumps will be fine as they are. Think about how many pumps out there never see a single bit of maintenance yet still work perfectly fine. However, in the interest of long-term reliability, I can come up with a few valid maintenance concerns (ordered from most to least frequently encountered):

Moisture could rust internal components if the pump is left out in the rain. You probably shouldn't store the pump outside on the bike if it's raining, and it would be a good idea to give the pump a few firm shakes to expel any water after a wet ride.
The internal O rings should probably be cleaned or replaced every few years if the pump's construction allows for that. Afterwards, they should be relubricated with a compatible weather-resistant grease. Don't use too much lest you clog the gauge with grease.
Over a longer timeframe (many years), the hose may develop cracks. It's often possible to replace the hose if needed.
I don't think you can really do much about protecting the gauge. They're usually sealed units.

It's probably also good practice to "exercise" the pump every so often (a few times a year?) to A: distribute and refresh the lubricant, and B: ensure the pump still works.

Sadly, my pump gets used regularly - longest I've gone without a flat on one bike is ~6 months.

@Criggie Have you considered going tubeless? :D (The first rule of the tubeless club is that you must talk about the tubeless club.)

@Torben no.  I'm a frugal cyclist, and road tubeless would mean new rims and tyres at the minimum.  Plus, the question is specific to pump maintenance, and AFAIK tubeless still uses air which means a pump on the bike.   I don't have any backup driver to come and save me from any lack of preparation, and would end up walking if I can't ride.

The gauge on a Road Morph isn't sealed.

Sure you'd still carry a pump, you just wouldn't need to use it except for maybe once every two years instead of 2x every year

@PaulH to me that sounds like more chance for it to degrade unnoticed. My pump often comes out to top up friends' tubeless tyres

@ChrisH I guess, but I’m not sure what your point is. I would prefer to do a quick check on my pump every 6 months in my garage to confirm that it works as expected if the alternative was using it to fix a flat (in the cold rain far from home) twice a year

@PaulH the main test is pumping up to full pressure, so if you make a habit of using it for routine top-ups, that's fine

I dunno man. I’ve never had an issue with pumps going bad. I’ve had a lot of tubes go flat. I’ve had very few tubeless tires go flat. There’s really not an issue here.

Most pumps don't require that their O-rings get regular service, but Lezyne does have service instructions! Also, Silca pumps do explicitly ask for occasional maintenance. A couple people on a different forum complained that they bought their frame pumps, only to find them not work on the road. I service mine every two years because I don't want to be that guy with the expensive frame pump that doesn't pump.
